# TypeError: jeu() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a little game and I'm stuck with an error.

> "TypeError: jeu() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)"

I don't really know if the code is even correct. I'm a beginner with `python` and `tkinter`

```
def jeu(arg):
  root2 = Tk()
  root2.title("Binary Game")
  root2.geometry("500x350+50+50")
  root2.resizable(width=False, height=False)
  root2['bg'] = 'black'
  #####
  menu = Menu(root2)
  root2.config(menu=menu)
  subFichier=Menu(menu)
  menu.add_cascade(label="Fichier", menu=subFichier)
  subFichier.add_command(label="Nouvelle partie")
  subFichier.add_separator()
  subFichier.add_command(label="Quitter", command=root2.quit)
  #####
  difchoisie = Label(root2, pady=30, text="Donnez la valeur décimale 
  de ce nombre : ", font=("Courier New", 18), bg="black", 
  fg="green").pack()
  nbdisp = Label(root2, text=nb, font=("Courier New", 20), 
  bg="black", 
  fg="green").pack()
  entrynbdec = Entry(root2, width=5, font=("Courier New", 20), 
  justify=CENTER).pack(side=TOP, pady=30)
  boutonvalid = Button(root2, text="Valider", 
  highlightbackground="black").pack()
  root2.mainloop()

root = Tk()
root.title("Binary Game")
root.geometry("500x350+50+50")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root['bg'] = 'black'
#####
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
subFichier=Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Fichier", menu=subFichier)
subFichier.add_command(label="Nouvelle partie")
subFichier.add_separator()
subFichier.add_command(label="Quitter", command=root.quit)
#####
bienvenue = Label(root, pady=30, text="Bienvenue sur Binary Game !", 
font =("Courier New", 24), bg="black", fg="green").pack()
choixdif = Label(root, pady=25, text="Veuillez choisir la . 
difficulté.", font =("Courier New", 18), bg="black", 
fg="green").pack()
boutondif1 = Button(root, text="Facile", highlightbackground 
="black", command=jeu).pack()
boutondif2 = Button(root, text="Moyenne", highlightbackground 
="black", command=root.destroy and jeu).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your function definition, `jeu()` is currently assumed to accept one argument `arg`

```
def jeu(arg):
```

However, in all your function definition, you are no where using any passed arguments, neither are you passing any arguments to it which is why you are getting the self explanatory error

> TypeError: jeu() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

where that **"exactly 1 argument"** refers to `arg` defined in the function definition **`def jeu(arg):`**

Hence, just use a function definition without any arguments as

```
def jeu():
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Bazingaa's answer, the function `jue()` doesn't need to have any arguments, as functions bound to `tkinter` buttons don't pass events (unlike keyboard bindings).

However, if you did want to pass values to `jue`, then you would need to use something like the `functools` library, which has the `partial` function.

For example:

```
import functools

def jue(arg):
    #code here

#rest of code

boutondif1 = Button(root, text="Facile", highlightbackground 
="black", command=functools.partial(jeu, some_args)).pack() #replace some_args with the value(s) you would pass to the function

boutondif2 = Button(root, text="Moyenne", highlightbackground 
="black", command=functools.partial(jeu, some_args)).pack()
```

Note that if you want to use `root.destroy()` when `boutondif2` is clicked, then you would need to include `root.destroy()` in `jue()`. You could do this by adding a parameter to your function that, if set to `True`, calls `root.destroy()`, like so:

```
def jue(arg, do_destroy):
    if do_destroy:
        root.destroy()

    #rest of code here
```

Comment: thanks for the answer
i tried the "do_destroy" that you gave me to destroy the first window when i click on the button when the fonction jeu starts but it doesn't work
it says TypeError: jeu() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
when i delete (arg, do_destroy) so there's just 
def jeu():
    if do_destroy:
       root.destroy()
it just says global name do_destroy isn't defined